# LINQ to SQL query in related tables

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a library database with related tables.

[image: tables]

`dbo.boeken` (books) that only have the general data of a book.
PK is `BoekID`

There is a relationship with `dbo.BoekenGegevens` (Book data). These data for the book are the author, publisher and nur codes. An author and publisher have written and published several books.
FK is `BoekID`
(The other FK's belongs to Author / Publisher etc.)

The other table has the details of who owns the book.
FK is `BoekID`
A book can be owned by several libraries.

Now I want to do a search with a Linq query on the title of a book.
How do I build a LINQ query so that I only see the books that belong to the requesting library?

The Datasets:

```vb
Private dbBoeken As New BoekenDataContext
Private dbBoekenGemeenten As New BoekenGemeentenDataContext
Private dbBoekenGegevens As New BoekenGegevensDataContext
```

Code i use:

```vb
Dim searchTitle = From title In dbBoeken.Boekens
                  Where title.Titel = txtTitle.Text
                  Join bookid In dbBoekenGegevens.BoekenGegevens On bookid.BoekID Equals title.BoekID
                  Select title

dbGridView.DataSource = searchTitle
```

Error when execute the query:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The query contains references to items defined in a different data context.

Comment: Please share with us how did you try to solve your problem and where did you stuck.

Comment: Code and error are in the original post now. Sorry, i forgot

Comment: I'm afraid that's not supported. You can't issue a linq query against two or more different datacontexts. One way to solve this problem is query both datasource separately then do the join in memory. Please bear in mind the size of the returning data as well.

Comment: You shouldn't create one context class per table.

Comment: I didn't see the possibility either. But thanks for the suggestion. Thank you Peter.